# Cannot connect to clearDB on heroku with command line

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I have clearDB database setup on heroku and I have all the credentials to connect remotely. I am trying to connect to it through ubuntu terminal with the command format

> `mysql -u username -h host -p password`

But as I enter password, the terminal just hangs up and nothing happens.I have to forcibly close it. I don't want to use any third party tool.
Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot database name.
On your Heroku settings, database connection will be like this.

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
mysql://root:123456@us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net/heroku_11111111111?reconnect=true
```

Example

```
mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] -h[HOSTNAME] -D [DATABASE]
mysql -uroot -p123456 -hus-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net -D heroku_11111111111
```